# Is it possible to change the height/font size of an NSPathControl without subclassing NSPathControl/NSPathComponentCell?

Tags: cocoa

I'd like to increase the height of an NSPathControl as well as make the font size larger. Is there any way to do it without subclassing the control as discussed  [here](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/226871-design-advice-bread-crumbs-nspathcontrol.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I don't think so. It shouldn't be too hard to subclass the cell though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to modify NSPathControlItem/attributedTitle:

(Limitation: macOS 10.10+)

```
for pathControlItem in pathControl.pathItems {
    let range =  NSMakeRange(0, pathControlItem.attributedTitle.length)
    let attributedTitle = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: pathControlItem.attributedTitle)
    attributedTitle.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: yourColor, range: range)
    pathControlItem.attributedTitle = attributedTitle
}
```

Or try to create subclass.(I didn't test it)

PS
I did see that the question was asked in 2010 and know that the method mentioned didn't exist at that time. Hope it helped someone.